# Embeded Javascript as Base64 replacing source link does not load

Tags: javascript, html, base64

Plain text javascript inserting/replacing video source url.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
<!-- MP4 for Safari, IE9, iPhone, iPad, Android, and Windows Phone 7 -->
<source src="" type="video/mp4" />
<!-- WebM/VP8 for Firefox4, Opera, and Chrome -->
<source src="" type="video/webm" />
<!-- Ogg/Vorbis for older Firefox and Opera versions -->
<source src="" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
<script type="text/javascript">
function qk_jrzTTxyrt(){
var kicuVCSAFejq="/1.mp4?md5=53FnPoZdBclGOd0NViQ8niAge9U&expires=1489000505";
var zRKPUndrbBQP=document.getElementsByTagName("source");
zRKPUndrbBQP[0].src=kicuVCSAFejq;
}
qk_jrzTTxyrt();
</script>
```

The same as above but it is BASE64 ENCODED JAVASCRIPT

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
<!-- MP4 for Safari, IE9, iPhone, iPad, Android, and Windows Phone 7 -->
<source src="" type="video/mp4" />
<!-- WebM/VP8 for Firefox4, Opera, and Chrome -->
<source src="" type="video/webm" />
<!-- Ogg/Vorbis for older Firefox and Opera versions -->
<source src="" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
<script type="text/javascript" src="data:text/javascript;base64,CmZ1bmN0aW9uIHFrX2pyelRUeHlydCgpewp2YXIga2ljdVZDU0FGZWpxPSIvMS5tcDQ/bWQ1PTUzRm5Qb1pkQmNsR09kME5WaVE4bmlBZ2U5VSZleHBpcmVzPTE0ODkwMDA1MDUiOwp2YXIgelJLUFVuZHJiQlFQPWRvY3VtZW50LmdldEVsZW1lbnRzQnlUYWdOYW1lKCJzb3VyY2UiKTsKelJLUFVuZHJiQlFQWzBdLnNyYz1raWN1VkNTQUZlanE7Cn0KcWtfanJ6VFR4eXJ0KCk7"></script>
```

If I use my plaintext javascript example javascript executes and inserts the video URL/HyperLink into the HTML src="" tag just fine.

But when I base64 encode the javascript and use my base64 encoded example to do the exact same thing it DOES NOT insert the video URL/HyperLink into the HTML src="" tag.

Can anyone tell me why the base64 javascript does not execute / run or work. I have been testing with Firefox I don't know if it is just a browser related issue rather hoping someone can shed light on what I have done wrong.

Comment: Works perfectly for me in `Chrome 56.0.2924.28 beta (64-bit)` and in `Firefox Developer Edition 52.0a2 (32-bit)`.

Comment: The base64 encoded example works for you in Firefox 50.1.0 Windows 10 ? The video "/1.mp4" should be playable correct ?

Comment: From my tests further it seems just Firefox does not like this but have no idea why anyone else can tell me why the Firefox build I specified finds it problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my dilemma it turns out that all the other browsers apart from the Firefox build I was using did not have a problem.

And the soloution to allow the base64 encoded JavaScript in Firefox to replace the src="" HTML tag was to defer loading of JavaScript.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="data:text/javascript;base64,string" defer></script>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_script_defer.asp

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
<!-- MP4 for Safari, IE9, iPhone, iPad, Android, and Windows Phone 7 -->
<source src="" type="video/mp4" />
<!-- WebM/VP8 for Firefox4, Opera, and Chrome -->
<source src="" type="video/webm" />
<!-- Ogg/Vorbis for older Firefox and Opera versions -->
<source src="" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
<script type="text/javascript" src="data:text/javascript;base64,CmZ1bmN0aW9uIHFrX2pyelRUeHlydCgpewp2YXIga2ljdVZDU0FGZWpxPSIvMS5tcDQ/bWQ1PTUzRm5Qb1pkQmNsR09kME5WaVE4bmlBZ2U5VSZleHBpcmVzPTE0ODkwMDA1MDUiOwp2YXIgelJLUFVuZHJiQlFQPWRvY3VtZW50LmdldEVsZW1lbnRzQnlUYWdOYW1lKCJzb3VyY2UiKTsKelJLUFVuZHJiQlFQWzBdLnNyYz1raWN1VkNTQUZlanE7Cn0KcWtfanJ6VFR4eXJ0KCk7" defer></script>
```